# How to add advanced responses to a guessing game?

Tags: javascript, console

I am trying to make a number guessing game in which the user has 6 attempts to try and guess a number between 1-100. Using the code editor in **codehs** I created a program which fulfills the basic requirements.

The problem is i'm trying to give the user extended feedback so that if the users guesses two or more low guesses in a row, the message changes to "Sorry, that guess is STILL too low", and similar for 2 or more high guesses.

I have tried to create another variable to keep track of what the last guess result was. However I am having trouble coding the 3 different states it can be in. For instance, if an integer variable was used, the following values could be used to represent the different possible states:

- -1: No guesses have been made so far
- 0:  Last guess was too low
- 1:  Last guess was too high

If anyone has a better approach to this please suggest as I have not gotten this to work without giving me errors.

```
function start() {
    var tarNum = 50;
    //var randomTarNum = Randomizer.nextInt(1, 100);
    var userGuess;

    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        userGuess = readInt("Guess the number.")
        if(tarNum == userGuess){
            println("Correct guess");
            break;

        }else if(tarNum< userGuess){
            println("Guess was too high.");

        }else if(tarNum> userGuess){
            println("Guess was to low.");

        }
    }
}
```

Lets assume the random number was 50:

1. after starting the program my first guess is 10,
2. the console should print, "Guess was too low"
3. after guessing another low answer like 25,
4. the console should print, "Guess was STILL too low"

and similarly if the guesses were to high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the last guess in a variable called `lastGuess`, then check against that:

```
function start() {
  var tarNum = 50;
  var userGuess;
  var lastGuess;
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    userGuess = readInt("Guess the number.")
    if (tarNum == userGuess) {
      println("Correct guess");
      break;
    } else if (tarNum < userGuess) {
      if (lastGuess && lastGuess < tarNum) {
        println("Guess was STILL too high.");
      } else {
        println("Guess was too high.");
      }
      lastGuess = userGuess;
    } else if (tarNum > userGuess) {
      if (lastGuess && tarNum > lastGuess) {
        println("Guess was STILL too low.");
      } else {
        println("Guess was too low.");
      }
      lastGuess = userGuess;
    }
  }
}
```